# I cant update my collection in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

All is running perfectly ,but when i add a new item to the collection ,the view does not update the collection to display it. Here is the code

```
App.Views.Contacts = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('sync',this.addOne,this);
    },

    render: function(){

        this.collection.each(this.addOne,this);
        return this;
    },

    addOne: function(contact){
        var contactView = new App.Views.Contact({model:contact});
        this.$el.append(contactView.render().el); 
    }
```

});

I don't know ,why sync is not working

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle so we can easily debug your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y6LQL/

Comment: I guess you should be listening to 'add' event, rather than sync here.

Comment: stuck on the same bit - its from a tuts+ tutorial and can't for the life of me work out whats going on..... any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have ho render all items on `sync` event and render one on `add` event. Like this:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
},
```

Comment: А и мой пример не работает ,потому-что я получаю все данные с сервера... в JSON формате